# How to give rwe permissions to root, admin, and user1; in a directory where all files and folders are owned by user1(rwe)

Tags: debian, permissions, chroot, sshd, vsftpd

I have a directory called `/home/user1`. In this directory, is a counter-strike game server that requires the permissions of the folder and all the files in it to be `user1` rwe (read, write, execute).

What I am trying to do is set up debian's SFTP server, and jail user1 to user1's directory.

However the game server's permissions requirements are getting in the way.

Both vsftpd and sshd state that root permissions must set on the directories you wish to jail. Therefore when I set the directory `/home/user1` and all the files it contains to ownership by root, the game server doesn't start. But when I set the `/home/user1` directory and all the files in it to `user1` rwe permissions, the sftpd and sshd servers disconnnect in filezilla with the following message:

```
Response:   500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server

Now I can give `user1` chroot permissions in the ftp accounts, but then they are free to roam the server and this is not desirable.

What I need to do is give `user1` rwe permissions in vsftpd or sshd, that are jailed to the `/home/user1` directory.

In addition I would also like `admin` to be jailed to the `home` directory as well, but be able to manage game servers in `/home/user1`, `/home/user2`, `/home/user3` directories with rwe permissions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, execute permissions have an x bit, not an e one ;-)

It would appear that it is not possible to create a directory which is only writable by root (as required for a chroot jail) and at the same time writable by the user who will be running processes in that directory (as required for your game server). Therefore, what you want to do is not possible as per your problem statement.

However, you can do the following instead:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  /home/jaildir
drwxr-xr-x 5 user1 user1 /home/jaildir/user1
```

set the home directory of `user1` to be `/home/jaildir/user1`, and set the chroot jail in vsftpd to be `/home/jaildir`. The only downside of this method is that the ftp root will be one level above the actual "interesting" content.

Comment: Not possible in linux -surely not x)! Ok so put the server in `/home/jaildir/user1` and set the chroot jail in vsftpd to be `/home/jaildir`? What's the command to successfully chroot jail in vsftpd -I ask because I tried quite a few solutions and no matter what, when I chroot'd user1, I had access to the entire server from that account.